# About the practical benefit of the electromagnetic discovery in Cheops Pyramid

Tags: electromagnetism, nanoscience

There's this Newsweek article titled "Ancient Egypt: Incredible Electromagnetic Discovery in Great Pyramid of Giza's Hidden Chambers" ([here](https://www.newsweek.com/ancient-egypt-incredible-electromagnetic-discovery-great-pyramid-gizas-hidden-1049578)) that says that

> Now, an international team of physicists has found that, under the
>   right conditions, the Great Pyramid can concentrate electromagnetic
>   energy in its internal chambers and under its base.
>
> The results, which are published in the Journal of Applied Physics,
>   could help scientists to create new nanoparticles — particles between 1
>   and 100 nanometers in size — that could be used, for example, to develop
>   highly efficient solar cells or tiny sensors.

Above article links to [this article in the Journal of Applied Physics](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5026556).

Question:

Would the scientist somehow use this pyramid to create the nanoparticles, or did the discovery tell them something about electromagnetism that was not already known?

Comment: [Here's a link to the full paper](https://www.scribd.com/document/385863301/Electromagnetic-properties-of-the-Great-Pyramid-First-multipole-resonances-and-energy-concentration-balezin2018).

Comment: Dear lord, this one’s worse than usual. The scientists should be fired for being so intentionally misleading, and the journalists should be fired for their inexcusably poor fact checking.

Comment: Voting to migrate to skeptics (with some modification).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit to [Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Practical benefits:  probably sharpening razors and awakening mummies.

Comment: While I would very much like to close this or migrate it, the alarmingly poor fact-checking and inflammatory writing by Newsweek, coupled with some extremely irresponsible clickbait-grabbing by the authors and the J. Appl. Phys. editors, puts this ball on our court, I should think.

Answer (score 46):

The scientific interest is to use pyramids in nano technology. They just scaled up their calculation to the size of the pyramid at Gizeh to get media attention. The scientific interest of the Gizeh is zero, but it is great clickbait.

Comment: "*Due to the lack of information about the physical properties of the pyramid, the researchers had to use some assumptions when making calculations. For example, they assumed that there are no unknown cavities inside, and that the building material has the properties of ordinary limestone and is evenly distributed throughout the pyramid.*" They built a simplified computer model, made a bunch of assumptions, and did some calculations based on that simplified model and those assumptions. They didn't actually go to the pyramid and try it.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not an expert on nanoparticles, but from reading the article, the paper seems to be describing a *geometrical* effect of the shape of the pyramid - that it is particularly good at resonating and focusing the energy of the waves at those wavelengths.

So, presumably they are talking about creating nanoparticles with similar geometry, that would have similar properties of focusing EM energy. I highly doubt the pyramid itself would be used to create the particles - it wouldn't provide access to energy levels approaching anywhere near what could be achieved in a particle accelerator, for example.